# Using Goutte to crawl a table

Tags: php, goutte

I am using `PHP 7.1.33` and `"fabpot/goutte": "^4.0"`.

I am trying to parse a table that I got from a html page. I want to have the company name and the link.

When running my script I get: `Nodelist empty`

Find below my minimum viable example:

```
        const URL = 'https://www.marketbeat.com/ratings/by-issuer';

        $firmArr = array();

        $firm = [
            'name' => null,
            'sourceTEXT' => null,
            'sourceURL' => null,
        ];

        $client = new Client();
        $content = $client->request('GET', self::URL)->html();
        $crawler = new Crawler($content, null, null);

        $table = $crawler->filter('#form1 > table')->first()->closest('table');

        $table->filter('tr')
            ->each(function (Crawler $tr) use (&$firm, &$firmArr) {
                // name
                $name = $tr->filter('td:nth-child(1)')->text(); // nodelist ist emtpy
                $firm['name'] = $name;

                // link
                $TEMP = [];
                $tr->filter('td:nth-child(1) > a')->each(function ($link) use (&$TEMP) {
                    array_push($TEMP, $link->text(), $link->attr('href'));
                });
                $firm['sourceTEXT'] = $TEMP[0];
                $firm['sourceURL'] = $TEMP[1];

                // add everything to result array
                array_push($firmArr, $firm);
            });

        return $firmArr;
```

When trying to get the `$name` I get at the following line - `$name = $tr->filter('td:nth-child(1)')->text();` - that `nodelist ist emtpy`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I don't think the `'#form1 > table'` selector returns anything since the table is a few divs under the form. Try `'#form1 table'`. Also the first `tr` in the table doesn't have any `td` elements, it has `th`s.

Comment: @solarc Thx! How can I skip the first element?

Comment: inside the anonymous function before finding the name, you could check if there's any `th` and if so just `return;`

Comment: @solarc Thx! Can you provide a working example?